# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function issue with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

Am dealing with a project in code-igniter. I want to implement typeahead in it. I tested the demo of typeahead and it is working well(with jquery 2.2.2.min. and jquerybundle). But when i placed that inside my project folder (already designed with bootstrap3) my console is showing

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function
```

And i found that With Twitter Bootstrap 3 the typeahead plugin had been dropped. Hence i placed bootstrap3-typeahead.js from https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/blob/master/bootstrap3-typeahead.js. But still am getting the same bug. My script is as follows.

```
   <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>common/js/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>common/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>common/js/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>common/js/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>   
   <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>common/js/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

<div id="bloodhound">
   <input id="searchbox" class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="type here">
   <input id="otherbox"  type="text" placeholder="the right side box">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var source = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url:'testt?st=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
    }
});
// Initialize the Bloodhound suggestion engine
source.initialize();

$('#searchbox').typeahead(null, {
   // display: name,
   display: function(item){ return item.name},
   source: source.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
      suggestion: function (item) {
          return '<option value='+item.id+'>' + item.name + '</option>';
      }
  },
   limit:25

});
$('.typeahead').on('typeahead:selected', function(evt, item) {
    $('#otherbox').val(item['name']);
  })
 });

</script>
```

Please help me to fix this

Comment: are you placing it after bootstrap 3 main js?

Comment: nop. before that.

Comment: that's the issue I think. put it after.

Comment: i replaced the order. still the same issue.

Comment: Update your post to show the order that you have your script tags in

Comment: @maccettura please check my updated question

Comment: Just a question, but why do you have these three files included in the doc? bootstrap3-typeahead.js, bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js‌, and typeahead.bundle.js? the first two are the same file and you should only include one or the other and what is the last file the bundle one? is that the same file as well? Let me know if that is the issue.

Comment: when i removed typeahead.min.js nothing happend. error is the same. But when i removed typeahead,bundle.js it is showing a new error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Bloodhound is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

The docs for this plugin aren't super helpful but I think you will need to get the standalone Bloodhound file and use that.

I think your script tags should be like this:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>common/js/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>common/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>common/js/bloodhound.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>common/js/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
```

I would look into grabbing the min versions of boostrap and bloodhound too (I have them listed as the min versions in my example)